# Merge multiple object inside same array into a single object where duplicate properties may repeat in the result object

Tags: javascript

From This object how can I get the result mentioned bellow?

```js
const obj = {
  gopal: [{ height: "164" }, { weight: "75" }, { balance: "500" }],
  liton: [{ salary: "20000" }, { balance: "1000" }],
};
```

I want this result:

```js
const newObj = {height: "164", weight: "75", balance: "500", salary: "20000", balance: "1000"}
```

My try:

```js
const objc2 = {
  gopal: [{
    height: "164"
  }, {
    weight: "75"
  }, {
    balance: "500"
  }],
  liton: [{
    salary: "20000"
  }, {
    balance: "1000"
  }],
};

function outp(obj) {
  const objKeys = Object.keys(obj);
  let final = {};
  objKeys.forEach((item) => {
    let res = {};
    obj[item].forEach((item2) => {
      res = { ...res,
        ...item2
      };
    });
    final = { ...final,
      [item]: res
    };
  });
  console.log(Object.values(final).reduce(function(result, current) {
    return Object.assign(result, current);
  }, {}));
}

outp(objc2);
```

Comment: _"where duplicate properties may repeat in the result object"_ - The keys in an object are unique. You cannot have multiple entries with the same key.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: alright, thank you. but i need those same keys value, so what is the way??

Comment: Maybe this can be answered if you say why do you need it...

Comment: for multiple values you can have an array of values

Comment: You can use an array for same key.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not the best way to do this, but it is an option

```js
const obj = {
  gopal: [{ height: "164" }, { weight: "75" }, { balance: "500" }],
  liton: [{ salary: "20000" }, { balance: "1000" }],
};

let json = JSON.stringify(obj);
let keys = Object.keys(obj);

keys.forEach(k => json = json.replaceAll(`"${k}":`, ""));
json = json.replaceAll(/[\[\]\{\}]/g, "");

json = "{" + json + "}";

console.log(json);
const obj2 = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(obj2);
```

Comment: that is awesome!! Can i get access those duplicate keys individually from the json?

Comment: I dont think so, you would probaply need to check if its a duplicate and rename it to balance1 and balance2

Comment: got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy using an array when two items have the same key, you could do something like:

```js
const input = {
  gopal: [{ height: "164" }, { weight: "75" }, { balance: "500" }],
  liton: [{ salary: "20000" }, { balance: "1000" }],
};

const output = Object.values(input).flat().reduce((outObj, item) => {
  const [key, value] = Object.entries(item)[0];

  outObj.hasOwnProperty(key)               // if the key is already present
    ? Array.isArray(outObj[key])           //   if the attribute is already an array 
      ? outObj[key].push(value)            //     push the value in the array 
      : outObj[key] = [outObj[key], value] //     create an array with the current value + the new one
    : outObj[key] = value;                 //   otherwise add a new key/value pair to the object

  return outObj;
}, {});

// test
console.log(output);
```

- `Object.values(input)` would return a 2D array
- Then you use `flat()` to make a single dimension array from the 2D one
- Finally you use `reduce()` to loop through the array and produce the output object

Then you can access the values of the "duplicated" keys with `output.key[index]` (e.g. `output.balance[0]`)